# How to go from CMutablePointer<CGFloat> to CGFloat[] in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert an ObjC class that uses [Facebook's pop library](http://github.com/facebook.pop) to Swift. Pop uses quite a bit of C.

In ObjC, I have a block that looks like this...

```
prop.readBlock = ^(SHVGraphViewObjc *graphView, CGFloat values[]) {
                values[0] = [graphView.centerOffsets[idx] doubleValue];
            };
```

The equivalent closure definition in Swift would be

`prop.readBlock = {(graphView: AnyObject!, values: CMutablePointer<CGFloat>) in }`

What I can't figure out is how to convert the `values[0] = [graphView.centerOffsets[idx] doubleValue];` to Swift? How do I let Swift know that `CMutablePointer<CGFloat>` should be a `CGFloat[]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Just wanted to clarify a few things after learning a bit more from the [online documentation (PDF)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf).

There are a few commonly used pointer types in Swift, here is how they map to C equivalents:

### Pointers as Arguments

```
CConstVoidPointer     => const void *
CMutableVoidPointer   => void *
CConstPointer<Type>   => const Type * 
CMutablePointer<Type> => Type *
```

### Pointers as Return Types, Variables, and Arguments*

```
COpaquePointer      => void *
UnsafePointer<Type> => Type *
```

**NOTE:** Arguments follow this rule **only** when they are more than one pointer level deep, otherwise see above.

### Pointers for Class Types

```
CConstPointer<Type>              => Type * const *
CMutablePointer<Type>            => Type * __strong *
AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<Type> => Type **
```

### Swift Pointers

When using the `CConstPointer<Type>` pointer in Swift, you may pass any one of these:

- `nil`, which will be evaluated as a `NULL` pointer
- A `CConstPointer<Type>` value
- A `CConstVoidPointer` value
- A `CMutablePointer<Type>` value
- A `CMutableVoidPointer`
- A `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<Type>` value which will be converted to `CConstPointer<Type>` if necessary
- A `Type` value passed by address (`&` operator)
- A `Type[]` array

**NOTE:**`CConstVoidPointer` can take any of the above values as well.

When using the `CMutablePointer<Type>` pointer in Swift, you may pass any one of these:

- `nil`, which will be evaluated as a `NULL` pointer
- A `CMutablePointer<Type>` value
- A `Type` value passed by address (`&` operator)
- A `Type[]` array passed by address (`&` operator)

**NOTE:**`CMutableVoidPointer` can take any of the above in addition to `CMUtableVoidPointer` values.

So it would seem in your case that a `CMutablePointer<CGFloat>` could also be a pointer to an array of `CGFloat` values. Though I am not completely sure how to dereference that in Swift. (Perhaps the `as` operator?)

Comment: In this case, I am not calling into the block. Facebook's pop library calls it. What I need to know is how to use `values` as an array of `GCFloats` from *inside* the block.

Comment: I would say `CGFloat[]` should suffice for that, I'm sure Swift will marshal any pointers as arrays (similar to C# when interoping with C libraries).

Comment: If I change the input block to `CGFloat[]` from `CMutablePointer<CGFloat>`, it says `CMutablePointer<CGFloat> is not a subtype of CGFloat[]`.

Comment: Perhaps keep your `CMutablePointer<CGFloat>` as is. You can use `Array<CGFloat>.convertFromHeapArray(...)` and pass in the `RawPointer` and `owner` properties from the `CMutablePointer`. This is somewhat a shot in the dark for me though.

Comment: I found the solution here (https://twitter.com/BigZaphod/status/475137485602045952), but it looks like your latest edit covered it too. What I ended up doing was 

`let data = UnsafePointer<CGFloat>(values)
 data[0] = CGFloat(graphView.centerOffsets[index])`. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your solution to its own answer and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

While SiLo's answer is extremely detailed, the specific question here is answered by Ross' comments underneath it, so I thought I'd expand those into a full answer.

I needed to do this recently in order to interface with my GPUImage framework via Swift. For my Harris corner detector, I use a callback block on each processed frame that provides a C array of OpenGL floating-point values in X, Y coordinate pairs, along with the size of that array in pairs. I use a C array for performance, since this will be provided 30-60 times per second on live video. In Objective-C, I would set this up using code like the following:

```
UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ChairTest.png"];

GPUImageHarrisCornerDetector *cornerDetector = [[GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter alloc] init];

[cornerDetector setCornersDetectedBlock:^(GLfloat* cornerArray, NSUInteger cornersDetected, CMTime frameTime) {
    NSLog(@"Number of corners detected: %d", cornersDetected);
    NSLog(@"Corner 1, X: %f, Y: %f", cornerArray[0], cornerArray[1]);
}];

GPUImagePicture *inputPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];
[inputPicture addTarget:cornerDetector];
[inputPicture processImage];
```

After I deciphered the proper closure syntax, I couldn't quite figure out how to access the values of the input C array where I hand over corner coordinates to the processing block. [Sean Heber's tweet about this](https://twitter.com/BigZaphod/status/475137485602045952) points out one way to do this, which I used to translate the above Objective-C to the following Swift code:

```
let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "ChairTest.png")

let cornerDetector = GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter()

cornerDetector.cornersDetectedBlock = { (cornerArray:CMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:Int, frameTime:CMTime) in
    println("Number of corners detected: \(cornersDetected)")
    let corners = UnsafePointer<GLfloat>(cornerArray)
    println("Corner 1, X: \(corners[0]) Y: \(corners[1])")
}

let inputPicture = GPUImagePicture(image: sourceImage)
inputPicture.addTarget(cornerDetector)
inputPicture.processImage()
```

This appears to be functionally identical. It might be safer to use `.withUnsafePointer()`, but I haven't quite gotten the syntax on that down.