# How to get back value from CMutablePointer?

Tags: swift, core-foundation

I am trying to use some C foundation APIs like Launch Services in Swift language, but I am facing to a little misanderstanding of how to properly use CMutablePointer. I have the following code :

```
var itemInfo: CMutablePointer<LSItemInfoRecord> = nil
var path: CFStringRef = "/test.txt"
var isFile: Boolean = 0

let url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, path, CFURLPathStyle.CFURLPOSIXPathStyle, isFile)
let status: OSStatus = LSCopyItemInfoForURL(url, kLSRequestAllFlags, itemInfo)
```

It compiles fine, but how to access to the `CMutablePointer<LSItemInfoRecord>` value as a Swift `LSItemInfoRecord` struct type ? Maybe I just missed it, but I don't see where this is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)..

I also tried the following code, using `&` prefix, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051395/how-to-go-from-cmutablepointercgfloat-to-cgfloat-in-swift) :

```
var itemInfo: LSItemInfoRecord? = nil
var path: CFStringRef = "/test.txt"
var isFile: Boolean = 0

let url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, path, CFURLPathStyle.CFURLPOSIXPathStyle, isFile)
let status: OSStatus = LSCopyItemInfoForURL(url, kLSRequestAllFlags, &itemInfo)
```

But I get the following error : `Cannot convert the expression type 'OSStatus' to type 'inout LSItemInfoRecord?'`.

I also tried with a non-optional (`var itemInfo: LSItemInfoRecord`) but the compiler claims that `itemInfo` is not initialized, which is obviously the required behavior.

So, how I can get this running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the struct:

```
var itemInfo = LSItemInfoRecord(flags: 0, filetype: 0, creator: 0, `extension`: nil)

...

let status: OSStatus = LSCopyItemInfoForURL(url, kLSRequestAllFlags, &itemInfo)
```

Note that `extension` must be escaped because it's a keyword in Swift.

**Edit**

A complete example:

```
var itemInfo = LSItemInfoRecord(flags: 0, filetype: 0, creator: 0, `extension`: nil)

var path: CFStringRef = "/Applications/Safari.app"
var isFile: Boolean = 0

let url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, path, CFURLPathStyle.CFURLPOSIXPathStyle, isFile)

let status: OSStatus = LSCopyItemInfoForURL(url, kLSRequestAllInfo, &itemInfo)

let statusString: String = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil).takeUnretainedValue()

println("Status: \(status), \"\(statusString)\"")
println("Creator: \(itemInfo.creator)")
println("Flags: \(itemInfo.flags)")
```

prints

```
Status: 0, "No error."
Creator: 1936093801
Flags: 271599758
```

Comment: When I try this, the values in the struct don't seem to change from their original, initialized values? The filetype is still `0`, the creator is still `0`, etc. even after the call to `LSCopyItemInfoForURL()`

Comment: Wow, I even tried because it is a little "ugly" to have to do that, with a language like Swift...

Comment: @CraigOtis you're right, seems to not work. I also tried things around `itemInfo.withUnsafePointer { p in flags = p.memory.flags }` but all I get is memory bad access.

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying `filetype` or `creator` when your example is asking for "all flags" only. It is also possible your file doesn't exist. I have added a complete example (tested & working).

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you, it works now. @CraigOtis Check that the `/test.txt` file exists

Comment: Ah, good catch @Sulthan - I didn't realize OP's example was only requesting flags, and not all the available info.