# CMutablePointer - how to access it?

Tags: swift

Can anybody explain how to access `CMutablePointer<CGPoint>` presented below? I can't find the syntax for it. It used to be `->` in `Objective-C`, but here none of my solutions works. The solution presented in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051395/how-to-go-from-cmutablepointercgfloat-to-cgfloat-in-swift) works in the opposite way I need to find out.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: CMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let newPage = targetContentOffset->x + 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since Swift beta 5, `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)` has taken an `UnsafeMutablePointer` instance as its last argument. When this method is called by your scroll view, your implementation can access the underlying Core Graphics point through the pointer's `pointee` property.

Note that the spelling of `pointee` used to be `memory` before Swift 3.

Answer (score 55):

As @Eric mentioned in his update, the scrollViewWillEndDragging delegate now takes an UnsafePointer.  To update the Unsafe pointer, you just have to access the memory property.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory.y = x + 1
}
```

*Tested and working with Swift Beta 4.

**UPDATED FOR BETA 5** 
Swift Beta 5 scroll view delegate uses an UnsafeMutablePointer instead of UnSafePointer

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory.y = x+ 1
}
```

Answer (score 25):

**SWIFT 3**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    var scrollOffset = targetContentOffset.pointee
}
```

Comment: Apple should finally make this `inout` as they've said it in the 2013 WWDC session.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Xcode 6.3

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    var scrollOffset = targetContentOffset.memory.y
    println(scrollOffset)
}
```